# rails 4, turbolinks and cached views - strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a strange problem on the production env. I'm using rails 4, ruby 1.9.3, nginx, and unicorn, there are no suitable caching, except that which in in standard rails.

I suspect that the problem is related with turbolinks, but not necessarily, the point is that as I pass between the sites, and return back to them, I still see the old versions of those sites, for example, appears new order, I'm going to orders page and I see the old data, then after refreshing page I get new data, another  example when I'm logging in, flash message appears, than after clicking to another pages and returning to old one I still have this flash message (pls note, Im not using back button in browser).

Do you have any idea what is going on?

In dev mode, everything is ok (and Im using turbolinks as well)

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'I pass between the sites, and return back to them'?

Comment: Thanks Sergey for your comment, by this sentence I meant that on returning - by hitting back button or even clicking in to link (ie offers) I've got same data on site, not refreshed (if I added new offer), I had to refresh site, to refresh list of offers. But know problem is solved I don't know how ;), but it is. Cheers.

Comment: Ran into the exact same issue, I ended up disabling turbolinks for now until I can figure out exactly why this is happening.

Comment: same issue here, investigating at this time

Comment: not refreshing turbolinks was related to nginx configuration (expiration for documents/css/js files).